# Semantic search and text expansion query with self-deployed model in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp, semantic-search

I'm trying to use the elasticsearch text expansion query to implement semantic search on a rank features field. I've read the ELSER documentation and understand the process. I'm using a local/downloaded elasticsearch on docker (not connected to elastic cloud).

In this example they reference the ELSER model ID to query a rank features field:
[example text expansion query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0D4k.png)
If image is not working this is the example query

```
GET my-index/_search
{
   "query":{
      "text_expansion":{
         "my_embeddings.tokens":{ 
            "model_id":".elser_model_1",
            "model_text":"the query string"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I'm curious if there's a way to use this query but with a self deployed model (not on elastic cloud) rather than the ELSER model.

I have a self deployed model just not sure how to reference it within the text expansion query.